Jwts.parser() blocking call
i'm developing jwt provide/parse features with kotlin, spring webflux, and jjwt 0.12.6
https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt
i used BlockHound to find blocking call. then, blockhound detected a blocking call on code that uses jjwt library.
i think that SecureRandom.nextBytes() cause blocking call.
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler infrastructure.adapter.driving.web.auth.AuthController#verifyToken(VerifyTokenRequest) [DispatcherHandler]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/auth/token/verify" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
                at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:276) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:425) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.ensureBufferValid(NativePRNG.java:528) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:547) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:221) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:758) ~[na:na]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.Randoms.<clinit>(Randoms.java:29) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.JcaTemplate.<init>(JcaTemplate.java:109) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.JcaTemplate.<init>(JcaTemplate.java:104) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.JcaTemplate.<init>(JcaTemplate.java:100) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.CryptoAlgorithm.jca(CryptoAlgorithm.java:60) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.ConcatKDF.<init>(ConcatKDF.java:59) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.EcdhKeyAlgorithm.<clinit>(EcdhKeyAlgorithm.java:68) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.StandardKeyAlgorithms.<init>(StandardKeyAlgorithms.java:46) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645) ~[na:na]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:219) ~[jjwt-api-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:173) ~[jjwt-api-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts$KEY.<clinit>(Jwts.java:335) ~[jjwt-api-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParserBuilder.<init>(DefaultJwtParserBuilder.java:89) ~[jjwt-impl-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347) ~[na:na]
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645) ~[na:na]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:219) ~[jjwt-api-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:173) ~[jjwt-api-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.parser(Jwts.java:1069) ~[jjwt-api-0.12.6.jar!/:0.12.6]
                at infrastructure.adapter.driven.jwt.JWTAdapter.parse(JWTAdapter.kt:55) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]


in case of jwt provide feature, i resolved blocking call issue by creating NativePRNGNonBlocking SecureRandom and using .apply { random(secureRandom) }
private val secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNGNonBlocking")

Jwts.builder()
.signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)),Jwts.SIG.HS256)
.subject(type.name)
.issuedAt(Date())
.expiration(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiryDate))
.apply { random(secureRandom) } //here
.compact()

in case of jwt parse feature, i can't find the way to resolve the issue.
val claims: Jws<Claims> = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret.toByteArray())).build()                 .parseSignedClaims(token)

how can i resolve blocking call in that case?
